# Deleted @replies can get hidden in the global inbox

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, global-inbox, comment-replies, deleted-comments

@replying and deleting was a nice way of e.g. update notification, but now it doesn't seem to work anymore!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: i think our both question need to go together under "synchronisation issues" between global-inbox and recent replies.

Comment: @SilentGhost: the inbox was only how I noticed this, but this used to work before (e.g. I bumped @someone when someone replied @som after @somethree posted a comment), so it's another issue.

Comment: re the inbox text, i think it was always shortened. I think they truncate it by 50 chars on the word border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was never intended to work in the first place.